# Number of selection containing at least one of each kind.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

From 3 cocoa nuts, 4 apples, and 2 oranges, how many selections of fruit can be made, taking at least one of each kind ? Ans:315

My thought:

For any of our selection that contains at least one of each kind, we can choose 1 or 2 or all three cocoa nuts, 1 or 2 or 3 or all 4 apples, 1 or both oranges.

So we have 3 ways of selecting cocoa nuts, 4 ways of selecting apples and 2 ways of selecting oranges, that gives me $3*4*2=24$ ways of making a selection such that my selection contains at least one of each kind.

Question: How to arrive at number 315 :)

Comment: Yes. $$\left(\sum_{1\le r\le 4}\binom 4r\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{1\le r\le 3}\binom 3r\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{1\le r\le 2}\binom 2r\right)=315$$ What's your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

We can choose $1,2$ or $3$ from the $4$ apples in $\displaystyle \binom41+\binom42+\binom43+\binom44=(1+1)^4-\binom40=15 $ ways

Similarly for $3$ cocoa nuts, $4$ apples

Ultimately, we need to multiply each of the three cases

Comment: Well, we arrive at the given answer with this method, but how does it matter whether I choose 1st orange or 2nd orange?! all I am supposed to do is include one orange into my selection.

Comment: @Vikram, Please make sure that we understand the difference between "**at least** one" and "**exactly** one"

Comment: oh, wrong wording from my side, not confused about it, your answer helped, thanx